# Offline Armory does not let me sign transaction, how do I upgrade?

Tags: armory, installation, offline

I have an offline laptop that will not let me sign the transaction.  I am running Armory 0.92.3 and Bitcoin Core 0.9.2.1.
I know that I need to upgrade to a new computer.  Any thoughts how and the process would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Update the software first. Both Bitcoin Core and Armory. Most likely no need for new hardware.

Comment: What version of both would you use. I am in the process of downloading bitcoin core and it tells me another two weeks.

Comment: If you just install the bitcoin core client, it will download the whole blockchain again. You can transfer the *.blk files from the blocks directory to the new install directly to speed things up.

Comment: Add use the latest versions available in any case.

Comment: Still working on the problem.

Comment: Where are you stuck now? Is Bitcoin Core synced completely?